# How to compress WAV file in python?

Tags: python, mp3, wav

I have converted MP3 files to WAV format but how can I compress WAV file to very small size less or same size that of MP3 size without changing the file format

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import os

# files                                                                         
src_folder = "D:/projects/data/mp3"
dst_folder = "D:/projects/data/wav"

#get all audio file
files = os.listdir(src_folder)
for name in files:
    #name of the file                                                           
    wav_name = name.replace(".mp3", "")
    try:
        # convert wav to mp3 
        sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("{}/{}".format(src_folder, name))
        sound.export("{}/{}.wav".format(dst_folder, wav_name), format="wav")
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea that you can compress a wav file to such a small size?

Comment: The requirement "without changing the file format" is going to be very hard to fulfill. Unless you find an audio-specific compression format that uses the WAV container format, you'll have to use whatever format is mandated by the compression tools.

Comment: And "very small size less than MP3 size" is going to be very hard unless you find another lossy format (like MP3 is). That will of course affect the sound-quality.

Answer (score 0):

s1.export("output.mp3", format='mp3', parameters=["-ac","2","-ar","8000"])

The line of code managed to reduce my audio size by half its previous size. Hope this is helpful to someone